# How to avoid a line-exceeding statement in a description's item tag?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, description

Having a description like this:

```
\begin{description}
\item[One or several threads are operating concurrently on some data structure, which is bad because and also blablabla.]
\end{description}
```

How is it possible to avoid that this (admittedly long) tag is written to one line?
I want it to line break. Currently it is written to one line and goes outside of the document :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really think this is **not** the intended purpose of `\item[]`, but maybe using a `\parbox` would help:

```
\begin{description}
\item[\parbox{10em}{One or several threads are operating concurrently
on some data structure, which is bad because and also blablabla.}]
\end{description}
```

Comment: I fully agree in both points. However, I would use a length in `em` or `ex`, e.g. 10em or 15em or similar.

Comment: if used for all, consider redefining `\descriptionlabel` to hold the `\parbox` (that is rather useful)

Comment: @Martin: fixed!

Comment: Depending on exactly what the author wants, it might be preferable to set the width of the `parbox` to `\linewidth-\labelindent` (or whatever the itemize indentation length is called)...

Answer (score 6):

With `enumitem`:

```
\setlist[description]{style=unboxed}
```

(Syntax for 3.x. With 2.x use `\setdescription`). By default, LaTeX boxes description labels (in fact, all list labels), and `style=unboxed` does the obvious thing.

Comment: Much better than parboxing around, IMHO.

Comment: This is the easiest and cleanest option, in my humble opinion. I was also having the same issue, and it was totally solved with this solution (I was already using `enumitem`).

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions that might be better suited to what you actually want to achieve. Just use `itemize` or use `paragraph`s instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
\bfseries
\item An extremely long description that is written in bold and so on which is long enough to wrap properly
\item Another item
\end{itemize}

Or you could just use paragraphs:

\paragraph{A very long item with lots of words in it and so on and then some normal text}

This text is normal
\end{document}
```

If you want the indentation as well, there are packages that can help there. (To have a collection of paragraphs indented more...)

Comment: `\bf`!? You meant `\bfseries`!

Comment: @Martin you're right. I forgot the command `\bffamily`? `\bfshape`? I always forget these things...

Comment: Yeah, I know. I used to run `latexdef textbf` all the time to see the name again! :-) (`\textbf` uses `\bfseries` internally).